# Jenkins Delivery Pipeline View doesn't show pipeline jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pipeline, delivery-pipeline

I try to show some delivery pipeline instances in jenkins Delivery Pipeline View.

If the delivery pipeline instance is defined as ‘Free Style’ or ‘MultiJob Project’ everything works fine, but the Job does not appear in the Delivery Pipeline View when defined as ‘Pipeline’.

I tried the following:
my_pipeline-job as a Post-Build-action -> Build other projects (manual step) ->Downstream Project Names->my_pipeline_job
The result was a error message: my_pipeline_job cannot be build!

The message disappears when I tried to build it as:
my_pipeline-job as Post-Build-action ->Trigger parameterized build on other projects-> Build Triggers-> Projects to build->my_pipeline_job
But the results will not be shown in Delivery Pipeline View.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. As an additional note triggered 'Pipeline' jobs do not show up in the downstream project list of the 'Freestyle' job which triggers it.

Answer (score 1):

At present support for pipeline type projects in delivery-pipeline-plugin is in active development.

Refer the JIRA ticket for information & progress
[JENKINS-34040](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34040)